# How to push a range of revisions from svn to hg

Tags: svn, mercurial, hgsubversion

I am trying to migrate from Subversion to Mercurail (Hg). For that process I use `hg convert` command. I want only the newest revisions that are a year older to be migrated to Mercurial. I tried using the below command

```
hg convert --rev 4234 http://mysvn/myrepo/trunk
```

But the above command migrates only the revisions that are older than 4234 (4233, 4232,..... ,1 ,0)

How to get migrate to mercurial from `HEAD` to specified revision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need the SVN specific conversion config option [`svn.startrev`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Subversion).

You can either add it to a `[convert]` section in your `.hgrc`:

```
[convert]
svn.startrev=4234
```

or you can specify that config option on the command line:

```
hg --config convert.svn.startrev=4234 convert http://mysvn/myrepo/trunk
```

Please take note that the docs say this will work for single branch conversion only. If you have more than one branch, you should be able to use the [splice map](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--splicemap) option to accomplish your goal, but that might take some extra work.